# How can I make a button have a :active state for 1 second?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
 document.getElementById("aButton").click();
```

Is there any way at all that I can make this button maintain an active state for one second. The code works but there's no feedback to suggest the button was clicked.

Note that I am not using JQuery.

Comment: What element are you using? Actual buttons  / inputs have built in 'states'

Comment: It's a button element.  However when I send it a .click() it clicks but I don't see any change in the color of the button as expected because I have given the :active a different color.  When I click manually I do see a change.

Comment: Can you demo the code?...but it sounds to me as though you need to add / remove styling with a delay. `:active` only applies when the mouse button is down.

Comment: Just to clarify @Paulie_D's comment: When you trigger an event using JS, it's not triggering the "active" state of the element because the element isn't active. Instead, you are actually calling the event handler bound to that event on the element. When you "click" you also call that event handler, but you "activate" the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not setting an "active" state, but you can use the :focus psuedo-selector to define a CSS rule for the button and then set the focus() and then blur() it with a timeout later:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('click');
btn.onclick = function() {
    var testBtn = document.getElementById('testBtn');
    testBtn.focus();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        testBtn.blur();        
    },1000);
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g0hyfgwg/

Comment: When I just press a button normally does it get an :active state ?

Comment: Yes it does, but it's only active while your mouse is down. It's inactive when you release it. You can style for :active, but if you want to show it as "active" after the mouse is released, you need something like the above.

Comment: And you could define the :active and :focus styles the same, in your CSS.